# Is it possible for a composition and aggregation to share a part?

Tags: oop, uml

I'm creating a UML design class diagram where my classes "Borger" (danish) ended up being a part to two other classes (wholes) :

[image: uml design class diagram]

one relation is a composition and one is a aggregation. Is this possible? Why/why not?

Comment: Yes, the UML specification allows it. If you want to know whether this is the best solution for your problem, then please explain the problem. If you just want to know whether UML allows it, then please remove the ``java`` tag.

Comment: I wonder how a person (the `Borger`) can be composed by a score. That sounds more than strange. So I just guess that your design is broken. You should explain why you chose the aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two compositions to *Borger* because *composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in **at most one composite object at a time*** (§ 9.5.3 page 112 of [formal-17-12-05.pdf](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) ), but to have a composition (*AggregationKind* is *composite*) and an aggregation (with *AggregationKind* is *shared*) is possible.

The precise semantic of *AggregationKind* valuing *shared* is not given in the norm  : *precise semantics of shared aggregation
varies by application area and modeler* (still § 9.5.3 page 112 of [formal-17-12-05.pdf](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) ), so you can decide of its meaning allowing to be compatible with your case above.

However your case is a little strange and I recommend to use a composition and a simple property (*AggregationKind* is *none*) for readability reason.

Note in Java you always use pointers, an instance of *Borger* cannot be really a part ( but this is possible for instance in C++ ).

Comment: It would be better to start your answer with 'Yes'. The question is not about two compositions, so the first paragraph is irrelevant.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl it is not needed to have an answer to just say "yes", a remark is enough for that. If I use an answer this is to explain, and for me to speak about the case of two compositions is relevant and a good way to introduce the mix case. If you do not like to read more that 10 characters in an answer I am sorry for you ^^

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to insult you. My comment on your answer was only meant to give you a suggestion for improvement imho. Explanation is always good, but for readability, it is better to start by answering the question instead of by explaining what _would_ be the answer if the question were _different_. This might be confusing for some readers.

Comment: Comments can and will be flagged, especially if they are or appear unfriendly, but also if they don't seem relevant anymore. Mods will treat the flag and act accordingly. Anyway, you should consider comments as transient items that can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is allowed. To my knowledge, there is nothing in the UML specification that forbids it.